# Cad automation software GUI testing

Tags: user-interface, testing, automated-tests, cad, catia

We are working on a CAD automation software. The software requires the user to click on a certain surface in the 3D Model during the process. This surface is similar in most of the parts we will use, but requires to move the camera around the part to find it(Click&Drag).

Do you know any GUI testing tools that we could use to automate this process in the testing phase? There are plenty of testing tool but I can't find any that deal specifically with CAD recognition. Is this possible?

Comment: How about using CATIA macros? record and run them every time there is a change

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look to [SikuliX](http://sikulix.com/). It is not specific to CAD automation, but deals with image pattern recognition. You then can automate some actions (mouse or keyboard events, etc.) to be provided on areas that matches an image you define as pattern for your tests.

Scripts are in python, but you can also run it with at least java.

From my experience (my previous company used it as GUI  test automation for CAD and PDM client, with 3D visualization), it is quite easy to start and "play" with it. Then, you'll certainly have to think on how you can integrate it in your tests.